# OpenVPN Access Server has a lot of listening ports

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, port, netstat

I have setup [OpenVPN Access Server](https://openvpn.net/) for a small private cloud network.

It works great, but I am wondering about all these 900 ports showing up in netstat from part of the system called openvpn-openss. what is it, and what are these ports for?

There is no incoming traffic, since the firewall is not open on any of these ports.
there is only one user connected to the VPN at the moment.

```
netstat -tulpn | grep openvpn-openss
tcp   0   0 0.0.0.0:914   0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN   1317/openvpn-openss 
tcp   0   0 0.0.0.0:915   0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN   1325/openvpn-openss 
tcp   0   0 0.0.0.0:916   0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN   1333/openvpn-openss 
tcp   0   0 0.0.0.0:917   0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN   1341/openvpn-openss 
tcp   0   0 0.0.0.0:918   0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN   1349/openvpn-openss 
tcp   0   0 0.0.0.0:919   0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN   1357/openvpn-openss 
tcp   0   0 0.0.0.0:920   0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN   1365/openvpn-openss 
tcp   0   0 0.0.0.0:921   0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN   1373/openvpn-openss 
udp   0   0 0.0.0.0:922   0.0.0.0:*           1381/openvpn-openss 
udp   0   0 0.0.0.0:923   0.0.0.0:*           1388/openvpn-openss 
udp   0   0 0.0.0.0:924   0.0.0.0:*           1395/openvpn-openss 
udp   0   0 0.0.0.0:925   0.0.0.0:*           1402/openvpn-openss 
udp   0   0 0.0.0.0:926   0.0.0.0:*           1409/openvpn-openss 
udp   0   0 0.0.0.0:927   0.0.0.0:*           1416/openvpn-openss 
udp   0   0 0.0.0.0:928   0.0.0.0:*           1423/openvpn-openss 
udp   0   0 0.0.0.0:929   0.0.0.0:*           1430/openvpn-openss
```

**Output from `ps -efc`**

```
# ps -efc | grep openvpn
root         676       1 TS   19 Oct02 ?        00:06:38 python2 -c from pyovpn.sagent.sagent_entry import openvpnas ; openvpnas() --logfile=/var/log/openvpnas.log --pidfile=/run/openvpnas.pid
openvpn+    1317     676 TS   19 Oct02 ?        00:00:02 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
openvpn+    1320    1317 TS   19 Oct02 ?        00:00:02 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
openvpn+    1325     676 TS   19 Oct02 ?        00:00:02 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
openvpn+    1329    1325 TS   19 Oct02 ?        00:00:02 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
openvpn+    1333     676 TS   19 Oct02 ?        00:00:02 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
openvpn+    1337    1333 TS   19 Oct02 ?        00:00:02 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
openvpn+    1341     676 TS   19 Oct02 ?        00:00:02 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
openvpn+    1345    1341 TS   19 Oct02 ?        00:00:02 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
openvpn+    1349     676 TS   19 Oct02 ?        00:00:02 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
openvpn+    1353    1349 TS   19 Oct02 ?        00:00:02 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
openvpn+    1357     676 TS   19 Oct02 ?        00:00:02 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
openvpn+    1361    1357 TS   19 Oct02 ?        00:00:02 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
openvpn+    1365     676 TS   19 Oct02 ?        00:00:02 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
openvpn+    1369    1365 TS   19 Oct02 ?        00:00:02 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
openvpn+    1373     676 TS   19 Oct02 ?        00:00:02 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
openvpn+    1378    1373 TS   19 Oct02 ?        00:00:02 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
openvpn+    1381     676 TS   19 Oct02 ?        00:00:03 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
openvpn+    1388     676 TS   19 Oct02 ?        00:00:03 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
openvpn+    1395     676 TS   19 Oct02 ?        00:00:32 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
openvpn+    1402     676 TS   19 Oct02 ?        00:00:03 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
openvpn+    1409     676 TS   19 Oct02 ?        00:00:03 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
openvpn+    1416     676 TS   19 Oct02 ?        00:00:03 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
openvpn+    1423     676 TS   19 Oct02 ?        00:00:03 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
openvpn+    1430     676 TS   19 Oct02 ?        00:00:03 openvpn-openssl --errors-to-stderr --config stdin
openvpn+    3580     676 TS   19 Oct05 ?        00:01:34 /usr/bin/python2 -c from pyovpn.cserv.wserv_entry import start ; start() -no -u openvpn_as -g openvpn_as --pidfile /usr/local/openvpn_as/etc/tmp/wserv.pid -r epoll
root       22133   21987 TS   19 00:43 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto openvpn
```

Comment: What have you got in the openvpn config file?

Comment: I configured everything using OpenVPN Access Server admin GUI. 
I looked around in /etc and /usr/share but found nothing. I have no idea where the GUI saves configs. But I described the setup on askubuntu in a question I ended up answering myself: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279187/openvpn-access-server-and-network-manager.

Comment: That doesn't really help, we need to see the server.conf file that was generated. You could run `ps -efc` to find the openvpn process and look at it's cmd line arguments to find the file.

Comment: The config seems to be saved in *.db (binary) files in /usr/loca/openvpn-as/db/. There is no server.conf. I have updated the post with output from `ps -efc`.